# Feature not showing on zoom levels, despite scale range (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles, zoom, mbtiles, visibility

I have an MBTiles file I am editing in QGIS. I have isolated the "transportation" layer to only show roads, and **I want the major roads to appear at all zoom levels**:

However, these major roads only show at zoom level 20 to ~5.5 but not beyond that, or at scale 1:12000000 or lower. This is regardless of any rules I have set on the lines. For example, I've tried the following on the 'stroke style' of this feature but neither solved my issue:

```
if(@map_scale <25000000, 'solid', 'no')

CASE WHEN @map_scale <25000000 THEN 'solid' ELSE 'no' END
```

**What I want to see at all zoom levels**
[image: What I want to see at all zoom levels]

**What is happening**
[image]

If I merge the major roads using *Vector > Geometry Tools > Multiparts to Singlepart...* then they do appear at all zoom levels, but they do not simplify when zooming out. Setting scale visibility on the 'transportation' layer hasn't helped either.

So what else could be causing my major roads from disappearing at certain zoom levels and how can I stop that from happening?